# Add values to a combobox in c#.net from SQL Server

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

Tried a few set of codes for populating a combobox from a table in SQL Server, but to no avail! The combobox is in a WindowsApplicationForm.This is the code I am using

```
public void BindData1()
{
    myConnection prms = new myConnection();

    using (SqlConnection con = prms.GetConnection())
    {
        string query = "select CountryName from Countries";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
        DataSet dt = new DataSet();
        d.Fill(dt);

        comboBox1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]; 
        comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
    }
}
```

The method is called at form load event, but there are no values in the combobox at runtime.

Comment: I don't see opening the connection. Is is not required?

Comment: Using a class for the connection string and opening the connection, and creating an instance of it

Comment: you already verify if the data They're coming in the DataSet? Place an break point in the line d.Fill(dt) and see it.

Comment: @Nimesh no, the DataAdapter opens and closes it if it is closed

Comment: @newuser your code should work as is but, do you use the shortcut |DataDirectory| in your connection string? If yes probably there is no data in the database pointed by the shortcut.

Comment: @steve No i don't use DataDirectory.

Comment: @GrantWinney just one blank entry

Comment: Code looks working ok. You need to check, as mentioned in the comments, if method `BindData1` is executed, or check if you have some other code which reset `comboBox1.DataSource`. And of course check if query return any row

Comment: Thanks all! It worked :) Just one more query though..i can't access any other control on my form except this combobox..the cursor gets stuck on this combobox! Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
```

You should use:

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: `comboBox1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]; ` is right, because `dt` is `DataSet`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DataTable` instead of `DataSet`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
d.Fill(dt);

comboBox1.DataSource = dt; 
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
```

Comment: No values are being displayed in the combobox!

Comment: @newuser Try to debug to see if there is data loaded in your DataSet, maybe your query doesn't return anything.

Comment: I tried the same query in sql, gives me the entire column.

Comment: @newuser Are you even calling that method? Because everything looks fine to me.

Comment: @newuser Have you checked if form load event is attached to your form? Also, while debugging, can you see that DataSet actually contains data inside it after Adapter fill method?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to replace it with following code.  I am not sure what you have in myConnection class but just try with this and let me know if it works.

```
    public void BindData1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("your Connection String"))
        {
            con.Open();
            string query = "select CountryName from Countries";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

            SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
            DataSet dt = new DataSet();
            d.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                comboBox1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
                //comboBox1.ValueMember = "CountryName";
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("No Countries found");
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
comboBox1.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "CountryName";
```